# Uploaded Linux Poseidon to Ubuntu 14.04. Pinging but not surfing

Tags: 14.04, internet

I have a partitioned Lenovo R500 with Windows XP (32 bit) and a Linux Poseidon (64 bit). Upgrading Linux to the newer Ubuntu 14.04 version, I cannot surf in internet although it pings (Windows does). 
I restarted the router, nothing. 
Tried wifi and cable, nothing.
I run the following codes:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4: 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1693] (rev 02)

ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:68:0c:24:ec  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:6b:73:82:7b  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4399989 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:439491 (439.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:602845 (602.8 KB)  TX bytes:602845 (602.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:fa:bd:96:76  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:518 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:74594 (74.5 KB)  TX bytes:56006 (56.0 KB)

route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
```

When I tested if it pings, it seems it does:

```
ping -c3 91.189.94.12

PING 91.189.94.12 (91.189.94.12) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from 91.189.94.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=50.0 ms 
64 bytes from 91.189.94.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=36.1 ms 
64 bytes from 91.189.94.12: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=54.7 ms

--- 91.189.94.12 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.147/46.977/54.733/7.892 ms
```

Is there any tip to solve this issue, please?
Thank you,
XXXL

Comment: Add DNS servers to network connection. Can put `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks! I did it already. I forget to mention, but it was not helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkManager is the program which (via the resolvconf utility) inserts address `127.0.1.1` into `resolv.conf`. NM inserts that address if an only if it is configured to start an instance of the dnsmasq program to serve as a local forwarding nameserver. That dnsmasq instance listens for queries at address 127.0.1.1.

If you do not want to use a local forwarding nameserver then configure NetworkManager not to start a dnsmasq instance and not to insert that address. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and restart the NetworkManager service.

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

In this mode, NetworkManager updates `/etc/resolv.conf` (still via resolvconf) to include the nameserver addresses NetworkManager has for active connections.

If you want to disable the resolvconf mechanism for updating resolv.conf and just use a static resolv.conf file, do the following.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  # Delete the symbolic link
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf   # Create static file

# Content of static resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: DOOONEEEEE! It took some time and a bit of help from a friend, but this was the right answer! Thank you very much, LX

Comment: Great, I'm glad I can help.

Comment: Also you can upvote and accetp answer :)

Comment: OPS, I though I did it, but apparently I have not, sorry! Tell me please if now is ok!

Comment: Everything is ok